# MySQL fast query to get latest five records

Tags: mysql, greatest-n-per-group

i have this query to get 5 latest post of each user. it works fine on small amount of data. but on live where i have millions of data. it's not very fast. it's taking too long. if anyone have idea to optimize the query so it's fast on large amount of data.

```
select p.*
from posts p
where p.id  >= (select p2.id
                      from posts p2
                      where p2.user_id  = p.user_id
                      order by p2.id desc
                      limit 1 offset 4
                     )
                     order by p.user_id ;
```

Comment: Use `partition over (select ...)`.

Comment: What is the goal of such a query without limit on the users? if each user has only 5 posts, the query is supposed to return millions/5 of posts ?

Comment: @Wiimm can you please give me a example ?

Comment: What is precise MySQL version?

Comment: MySQL version is 5.7

Comment: no there is thousands of users and millions of posts, so i want to get only five post of each user. @N69S

Comment: @RizwanShahzada so millions - 4 x thousands of results, so still millions of results in a single query. how fast do you expect it to be when each result has to run a subquery to check for that condition?

Comment: Sorry, but I wrote a wrong syntax in my first fast comment. Read https://mariadb.com/resources/blog/introduction-to-window-functions-in-mariadb-server-10-2/ section "Top-N Queries" for details. Or search for `mysql window functions`.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12113699/get-top-n-records-for-each-group-of-grouped-results

Comment: That query looks "wrong".  The outer part says `p.id >= ...`, which will include posts from a variety of `user_ids`.  See the tag I added.

Comment: Alas, the "partition over" technique makes two read passes over the table and one write pass.

Comment: With, say, 1000 users, you really want 5000 rows in the resultset?